# Storing GPS location in postgis efficiently?

Tags: postgis

I'm getting info from GPS And I have 4 data :

- latitude
- longitude
- altitude
- precision

Can I store the precision in M coordinate in PostGIS?

Ex :

```
 CREATE TABLE gps_pos ( id uuid primary key, position Geometry(Point, 4326))
 INSERT INTO gps_pos (id, position) VALUES (<uuid>, ST_MakePoint(0.0, 0.0; 400.0, 20)
```

I never used this 4th coordinate and don't know the best practice about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *M* is usually reserved for *Linear Referenced* positions (in a *Linear Referencing System*). There are GIS tools that understand and operate specifically on the *M* values.

The *precision* values from GNSS do not indicate positions of any kind (but rather the quality of the XYZ), and thus is best kept in a normal field to avoid confusion.

Comment: It's also worth noting that [dillution of precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_(navigation)) can be split in in *horizontal* and *vertical* components, and sometimes even in a *time* component. It's nearly impossible to have those two/three values in the same *M* field, so keeping them separate makes even more sense.

Comment: Ok so if i read correctly. I should have a table like :

    CREATE TABLE gps_pos (id SERIAL, precision float, position Geometry(Point, 4326) 

Do you have any reference about this M values, I'm currious

Comment: Yes. And, as Ivan Sanchez had commented, it would be good if you know which *precision* you were given although my guess is that it is (usually)  PDOP (under most situations). [HDOP and VDOP are always given together, and TDOP is of interest for timing-related operations.] And, for more explanations for the M value, lookup Wikipedia - search for "Linear Referencing System".